# How can i check the module-name in `cont` type transactions for gas-station?

Tags: pact-lang, kadena

I have implemented a gas-station for my project.
When i tried to pay gas for a `cont` type txn, and it threw me `Inside an exec` error.

```
(defcap GAS_PAYER:bool
    ( user:string
      limit:integer
      price:decimal
    )
    (enforce (= "exec" (at "tx-type" (read-msg))) "Inside an exec")
    (enforce (= 1 (length (at "exec-code" (read-msg)))) "Tx of only one pact function")
    (enforce (= "(free.anedak." (take 13 (at 0 (at "exec-code" (read-msg))))) "only free.anedak smart contract")
    (compose-capability (ALLOW_GAS))
  )
```

While looking at the code, I found that only `exec` type transactions are supported in gas-stations and the ability to check that the txn call is made only by my contract is only possible in `exec` type txns.

The data to check for module name and txn types are added in this block of code.

https://github.com/kadena-io/chainweb-node/blob/0b24dd35a7fda27719ea7a2ca54db2cfd1196d95/src/Chainweb/Pact/TransactionExec.hs#L876.

I don't think i can use the existing props for checking the module name in `cont` type txns.

https://github.com/kadena-io/chainweb-node/blob/8c32fcfff85c4e5b61a9554f0180ca6c90840e42/test/pact/continuation-gas-payer.pact
I found this one for `cont` type txns, but no checks on module name.
Any solutions on how i can check the module-name in cont type txns will be helpful as this will prevent my gas-station from spamming.